# Update webform submitted data through the DataBase?

Tags: 7, database, webforms

I see in the DataBase the table `webform_submitted_data` which contains the components's data of all webforms

But a token suddenly stop working as intended so the hidden fields of the webform, its data were incorrect for my use case. I fixed the issue but now want to update the affected submissions (luckly are only 10)

It is safe to update the respectives rows through a SQL statement? I do not need to trigger hooks, or other stuff, only need the correct data for the little code i write that uses it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be perfectly safe to do.

Take a backup first just in case, clear the cache after you've done it, and that should be fine.